# Tableau Donut Chart With Text In Centrer

Tags: tableau-api

I am completely new to tableau and I got a requirement of creating a donut chat with showing text in center of that chart . I created a PIE chart with all necessary data and calculations but not sure how to convert that PIE chart in to a DONUT . I have multiple legends . Something like below . 
Requeestig for help on this .

[image]

Comment: using google: "Tableau donut chart": http://community.tableau.com/thread/158686, http://www.datascienceriot.com/how-to-make-kpi-donut-charts-with-tableau/kris/, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amdR9SzcHDs, ...  where are you missed?

Comment: Thanks a lot . I got it worked from first example .

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Create a calculated field as 0.
2. Place it in the column shelf. Duplicate the calculate field in the Column shelf.
3. Select 2 Calculation - Right click and select the dual axis.
4. Now we see 2 marks in the mark card. Both are Circle in shape.
5. Change first Donut(calculation) to Pie and the second to Circle.
6. Modify the size of both Donuts to get the correct design.
7. Keep any measure you want in the second mark - Label. Change the alignment to middle and center.

Regards,
Deepak

Answer (score -2):

https://www.interworks.com/blog/tmccullough/2014/03/06/tableau-cookbook-donut-charts.

Have a look and you will know. There is a cookbook you can download. Detail solutions are included in the file.